# How to update a dictionary with different list elements in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary with the following structure:

```
{"filename_1.wav": {
    "name": "sp1",
    "embedding": [0, 1, 2, 3]
    },
"filename_2.wav": {
    "name": "sp2",
    "embedding": [4, 5, 6, 7]
    },
"filename_3.wav": {
    "name": "sp3",
    "embedding": [8, 9, 10, 11]
    },
}
```

The keys `name` and `embedding` in the inner dictionary stay the same whereas their values change according to the filename.

This is my code so far:

```
outer_dict = {}
inner_dict = {}

audio_filenames = ['filename_1.wav', 'filename_2.wav', 'filename_3.wav']
embeddings = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
speaker_ids = ['sp1', 'sp2', 'sp3']

for audio in audio_filenames:
    outer_dict[audio] = inner_dict

for e in embeddings:
    for s in speaker_ids:
        inner_dict['name'] = s
        inner_dict['embedding'] = e

print(dict(outer_dict))
```

My output looks like this:

```
{'filename_1.wav': {
    'name': 'sp3', 
    'embedding': [8, 9, 10, 11]},
 'filename_2.wav': {
    'name': 'sp3', 
    'embedding': [8, 9, 10, 11]}, 
'filename_3.wav': {
    'name': 'sp3', 
    'embedding': [8, 9, 10, 11]}
}
```

As you can see, only the audio filenames are updated correctly, whereas from the speaker id and the embeddings lists only the last element is taken.

Can anyone please give me a hint regarding how I can update the speaker ids and the embeddings as well?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here.

You are currently overwriting the same inner dictionary, and all `outer_dict`values are pointing to the same `inner_dict` object. You need to create a new `inner_dict` object for each entry in the outer dictionary.

Also, you do not want to use a nested `for` loop to assign the embeddings and speaker ids.

Instead, try assigning each key and its inner dictionary's values one-by-one. Here's an example:

```py
outer_dict = {}

audio_filenames = ['filename_1.wav', 'filename_2.wav', 'filename_3.wav']
embeddings = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
speaker_ids = ['sp1', 'sp2', 'sp3']

for i in range(len(audio_filenames)):
    inner_dict = {}
    
    inner_dict['name'] = speaker_ids[i]
    inner_dict['embedding'] = embeddings[i]

    outer_dict[audio_filenames[i]] = inner_dict

print(outer_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a comprehension-list expresion. If the three lists have the same length, then you can use this answer.

```
response_dict = {audio_filenames[index]: {'embedding': embeddings[index], 'name': speaker_ids[index]} for index, _ in enumerate(audio_filenames)}
print(response_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'filename_1.wav': {'embedding': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'name': 'sp1'},
 'filename_2.wav': {'embedding': [4, 5, 6, 7], 'name': 'sp2'},
 'filename_3.wav': {'embedding': [8, 9, 10, 11], 'name': 'sp3'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
audio_filenames = ['filename_1.wav', 'filename_2.wav', 'filename_3.wav']
embeddings = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
speaker_ids = ['sp1', 'sp2', 'sp3']

Dict = {}


for a,b,c in zip(speaker_ids, embeddings, audio_filenames):
    # print(a,b,c)
    Dict[c] = {}
    Dict[c]['name'] = a
    Dict[c]['embedding'] = b

print Dict
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for your contribution. Please review the accepted answer on this thread to get an idea of the level of explanation expected when submitting answers.

Comment: Avoid using reserved words like `dict`, `list`,  `tuple`, etc. As variable names